# Weaker version of Well-Ordering principle?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> Given a set $S$, I want to find *a total antisymmetric relation* $R$ on $S$:

$\forall i,j\in S$ either $iRj$ or $jRi$ or both.

In the case both, we have $i=j$, therefore any two distinct elements of $S$ have a fixed direction.

The *Axiom of Choice/Well-Ordering Principle* can work it out. But this is so muck weaker than *AC/WO*. So I am wondering if this is gonna work in *ZF-system*.

Answer (score 1):

This would imply a statement which is probably close in strength to the full Axiom of Choice.  That would be what we think of informally as the "choice of one sock from each pair in an infinite drawer": given a collection of sets $\{ A_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$ such that $|A_\lambda| = 2$ for each $\lambda$, then by the assumption that your statement is true, find a total antisymmetric relation on $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda$.  Then, for each $\lambda$, we can choose the element of $A_\lambda$ which is smaller than the other in this order, and thus construct a choice function for $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$.

Actually, a very similar argument will work in the more general case that each $A_\lambda$ is a finite set, if you strengthen the statement to assert the existence of a total order on every set (i.e. a partial order which also satisfies the given condition of being total antisymmetric).

Comment: The "infinite socks" principle is Form 88 in Howard and Rubin, and if I am using their database at http://consequences.emich.edu/conseq.htm correctly, they assert it is not provable in ZF.  As such this would also imply that OP's principle is also not provable in ZF.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh, I was thinking of the case where $R$ was a total order (i.e. also transitive) instead of just a "total antisymmetric relation".  I'll edit that side comment accordingly.

Comment: In fact, OP's principle is equivalent to form 88, isn't it?  A choice function on the set of all two-element subsets of $S$ would induce a total antisymmetric relation on $S$.

Comment: H&R assert that form 88 does not imply AC.  In fact, your "finite set" comment is form 62 (every set of finite sets has a choice function) and H&R assert that 88 does not imply 62.

Comment: Choosing socks is quite weak. Linearly ordering every set is quite weak. No, this is not close to choice in any reasonable sense of the word "close", at least when you look at this from up close. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, I was thinking in terms of many of the interesting restrictions of AC being primarily in terms of the "number" of choices to make - while this allows for an arbitrary number of choices since $\Lambda$ is an arbitrary set.

Comment: Yeah, but that's like saying that you can fly to Jupiter just because we're in the same galaxy. The majority of "interesting restrictions" would usually restrict the size of the family, or the underlying set, yes, but that just means that there are more to choice than just from "how many" or "how large" are the sets we choose from.

Comment: Also, note that any cyclical [directed] *graph* on three nodes is a total anti-symmetric order, but there is no notion of "smallest", since for that you need to be able and choose a starting point. So the argument does not generalize for arbitrary finite sets.